# Just changed a password, not in my keychain?

Tags: icloud, safari, google-chrome, keychain

I last used Twitter some time ago and no longer recalled my password. I did a reset and let Safari suggest a password.

I also have a PC where I use Chrome. Normally I would go into `Keychain Access` and show the password and then type it into Chrome. However, when I tried that this time, all the passwords for that service are from 2014.

Any ideas?

Also, is there a better way to do this? Is there some way I can use my iCloud keychain in PC Chrome?

Comment: My recommendation would be [a third party password manager](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-password-managers/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way. *Let me grab my small soapbox*.

It's always so hard to manage multiple password stores across multiple browsers, multiple devices and multiple OS.

In my experience, turn off all offers to save passwords and use one repository. If you're all in Apple iCloud - the keychain is OK for many / most. When that fails you or you're a power user, get 1Password.

If you need to have windows and other OS - get 1Password. It is paid software but your time is also valuable and I see it as an insurance policy against bad passwords and password reuse.

- https://1password.com

I can't imagine not having a system to remember all the fake security question answers, all the other details about account setup and most of all, not having a system to automate entry of unique passwords for each and every service so one breach doesn't spread to my entire digital life.

*off the soapbox, now*